# ASP.Net gridview editing - finding a control on a multipage grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, row

I have a gridview that has a textbox in one of cells in my aspx file.

After clicking the edit link in the row, I am able to get the control programatically in the rowdatabound event with this:

```
e.Row.FindControl("controlPlaceholder");
```

Using the edit index from the edit event works as well.

However, the control is only enabled on the first page of the gridview. On any other page, FindControl() returns null.

What could be the reason for this? Are there any potential solutions to this issue? I've looked for a solution but haven't had any luck with finding someone who has this particular problem.

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAccountAssignment" runat="server" CssClass="clsDataPanel" meta:resourcekey="pnlAccountAssignmentResource1">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvAccountAssignment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" OnRowDataBound="gvAccountAssignment_RowDataBound"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gvAccountAssignment_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gvAccountAssignment_RowEditing"
        OnRowUpdating="gvAccountAssignment_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="gvAccountAssignment_PageIndexChanging"
        OnSorting="gvAccountAssignment_Sorting" AllowSorting="True" meta:resourcekey="gvAccountAssignmentResource1">
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="clsGrayBkgCell" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        <Columns>
            ...Other Columns...
            <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource8">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="clsNumber" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="column13PlaceHolder" runat="server" CssClass="clsNormalLabel">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>      
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblprevMonth" runat="server" CssClass="clsNormalLabel"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="hypSortGLBal" OnClick="hypSortGLBal_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </HeaderTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            ...Other Columns...
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPrepPopulated" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You really need to post some code/html.  Generally speaking you should not need to enable/disable a control for editing when typically selecting edit from a gridview places the control into "edit mode" and makes data entry relatively trivial.

Comment: Sorry, the control does get enabled when clicking the edit button, but only on the first page. On any other page, it does not get enabled during edit mode and FindControl fails to find it.

Comment: Can you post your gridview markup from the aspx page?